# how to plot a 3d graph in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I am new to python and matplotlib, I want to plot a line graph and I have 3 arrays:

```
np.append(self.arraynv,nv)
np.append(self.arraysvdb,Svdb)
np.append(self.arraykclen,kclen)
```

which I want to be x, y and z axis points respectively 
the code I wrote:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Axes3D.plot(self.arraynv,self.arraysvdb, self.arraykclen)
ax.show()
```

The error I am getting:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'has_data'
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the issue is because you are not using the `ax` object that you created on this line `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')` to call the plot function on this line `Axes3D.plot(self.arraynv,self.arraysvdb, self.arraykclen)`.

The issue is that Axes3D is a class and not an instance of itself. The plot function is part of the class Axes3D, but to be able to call it, you need to use an instance of that class which is the object that you created called `ax` on the previous line.

Another issue is with your last line `ax.show()` which the show() function cannot be called through your object `ax`. Use `plt.show()` instead.

try this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(self.arraynv,self.arraysvdb, self.arraykclen)
plt.show()
```

Remember that class functions can only be called using an instance of said class then the function: `x.function(arg1,arg2)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.datasets import make_s_curve
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    '''
    make and plot 3d
    '''
    X, y = make_s_curve(n_samples=1000)
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

    ax.scatter3D(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], c=y)
    ax.view_init(10, -60)
    plt.show()
```